# why am i getting an error for my cipher function (python)?

Tags: python, design-patterns, encode, encryption

here's my code:

```
def encode(pattern, filename):
  pattern = ['a','e','s','3']
  message = open(filename, 'r+')
  for letter in message:
      if letter == pattern[0]: 
        letter == pattern[1]

      elif letter == pattern[1]:
        letter == pattern[0]

      elif letter == pattern[2]:  
        letter == pattern[3]

      else:
        continue

  message.close()
```

probably a few flaws in the code as I'm only an amateur at python, but when i run the function, the file remains unchanged. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a difference between `==` and `=`. `==` is used to test if two objects or primitives are the same, `=` is used to assign values to objects or primitives.

try making these changes:

```
for letter in message:
      if letter == pattern[0]: 
        letter = pattern[1] ## <-- change
      elif letter == pattern[1]:
        letter = pattern[0] ## <-- change
      elif letter == pattern[2]:  
        letter = pattern[3] ## <-- change
      else:
        continue
```

but this just assigns a value to `letter` which will be changed the next iteration through the loop, what you really want to do is write to some other file, or write back to `message` (but this could be dangerous since you are reading from it).

Comment: +1. It is also possible that `letter` contains line-feed and / or carriage-returns.

Comment: I tried it, same result though. I think the below poster might be on to something, the write function needs to be used, although not sure how..

Comment: @user1390754 Notice the last paragraph of my post where I say 'what you really want to do is write to some other file'

Answer (score 2):

I. Unless I'm mistaken, you're not actually editing the file, even with the `r+` mode, by making assignments to `letter`. You still need to use `write` to actually make changes to the file.

II. You may be interested in `string.translate`:

```
In [112]: t = string.maketrans('abc', 'bad')

In [115]: s = 'abcdef'

In [116]: s.translate(t)
Out[116]: 'baddef'
```

Comment: If you really want efficient in place editing then mmap is an excellent solution ...